# VBA, Excel: Can .OnAction value be set to a Public Sub which is in ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, menu, module, controls

VBA Geniuses:

*Question 1:*  Is it possible to set the **.OnAction** value of a menu option to a Public Sub which is in **ThisWorkbook** or must the sub be in a **module**?

This works: ViewTextFile() is a public sub in a **module**

```
.Controls(strMenuItem).OnAction = "'ViewTextFile """ & strMenuItem & """'"
```

I would like to move the sub to **ThisWorkbook**, so the value becomes something like this:

```
.Controls(strMenuItem).OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "!ViewTextFile """ & strMenuItem & """'"
```

*Question 2:*  If the answer to #1 is yes, then what is the syntax for getting the reference to "ThisWorkbook" into the .OnAction command?

Note that the parameter **strMenuItem** must be included in the value (as in, "ViewTextFile my_file.txt").  I have tried many variations of the above but no success.

Thank you, VBA geniuses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Controls(strMenuItem).OnAction = _
            "'ThisWorkbook.ViewTextFile """ & strMenuItem  & """'"
```